# Shockwave Adobe Flash Player - get video duration in javascript

Tags: video, adobe, flash, shockwave

I have a flash video and a embed code which display it.

I want to get the video duration in javascript.

Is it possible?

Embed code is like this:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="550" height="400" id="myFlashMovie" align="middle">
<param name="movie" value="myFlashMovie.swf" />
<param name=FlashVars value="myVariable=Hello%20World&mySecondVariable=Goodbye">
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="myFlashMovie.swf" width="550" height="400">
    <param name="movie" value="myFlashMovie.swf" />
    <param name=FlashVars value="myVariable=Hello%20World&mySecondVariable=Goodbye">
<!--<![endif]-->
    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
    </a>
<!--[if !IE]>-->
</object>
<!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you learn any solution to this issue?